# Simple Square's Flow Example/Tutorial Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dependency-injection

I'm having problems understanding Flow's sample app. It's too complicated. The documentation doesn't help at all.
https://github.com/square/flow
I hope someone can point me to a simple and clear example.

Comment: why you wish to use that? You can use fragments for smooth flow and write your own logic to keep the count

Comment: They say it makes code cleaner/less complicated. Though now i'm starting to doubt. Also I would like to learn this, declarative programming paradigm.

Comment: Little late but these blogs help me understand it. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/an-investigation-into-flow-and-mortar/ https://corner.squareup.com/2014/01/mortar-and-flow.html